# Set auto and fr grid template columns in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I need to apply this line of CSS to my layout:

```
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
```

Is this something you can't do with Tailwind CSS?

Comment: You may use [arbitrary](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) values like [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nQaVTfljXN)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the utilities using your Tailwind CSS config:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'my-columns': 'auto 1fr'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-my-columns">
  
</div>
```

Or you can use arbitrary values if you're only using this layout in one place:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-[auto_1fr]">

</div>
```

There's more details in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns).